# Problem with applying CSP policy for Google fonts file

Tags: django, content-security-policy

I'm working on Django site (upgrade from version 2 to version 4), where I have to apply Content Security Policy.
In other projects I did it with `django-csp` using project's settings, but in this case I only add `'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',` to `MIDDLEWARE` settings, and all CSP is done by `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...` tags. That's the first strange thing.

After rendering the code of my home page looks like this:
[image]

The error is:

```bash
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:wght@300' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'nonce-d0R7xtS9JR5LNg6UqQ5FCg=='". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The second strange thing is that I set the `style-src-elem`, but the error says I didn't.

And information from DevTools:
[image]

Why is it blocked?
The fonts are available [here](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:wght@300)
I used the hints from the official CSP site on Google fonts [here](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/google-fonts/) and everything seems to be OK, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you define multiple policies, the content needs to pass all policies. You have set 5 different policies in meta, and the policy mentioned in the error message is not among them, which means it is served as a response header. You will need to modify/remove the policy serverd as a response header. It could also be good to consolidate to only one combined policy, ideally avoiding using meta.